Is it safe to drive the car with this clutch issue (dry DSG, 7 speed)?
I have an Audi A3 with s-tronic (7 speed, dry DSG). I've found some videos on youtube with the exact same problem as mine:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuP5isxO78Y
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/g6wJJ1QjNnI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82it0ChT-8Y
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2Q8kW4QExY

I have had this problem before, they've replaced the clutch. 30k kms later, the issue came back. I guess they will replace the clutch again, but I have to wait 2 weeks before the mechanic can work on my car. Is it safe if I use my car with this issue? Can it be worse?

What do you mean by "safe"? For other people and property, or the car's ability and the safety of its driver?
Your last link isn't like the others, which have a clutch squeal.
I had a 2016 Skoda (VAG) 7-speed dry clutch DSG which exhibited the clutch squeal. It was fixed under warranty but within 30k miles it began squealing again, and I drove it to 90k before selling it, without any hint that there was a safety issue.
I understand that this particular gearbox variant was withdrawn.
The only issue I noticed was a slight tendency to judder when pulling away rapidly while turning, for example from a side road into a traffic gap.

By safety I mean that I don't wanna cause bigger trouble. Previously I had the clutch squeal problem seen in the last video, but now I have the other one.

I can only repeat that I drove for 30,000 miles with a squealing clutch, without further damage.

I understand. But you've said that the first 3 is not a clutch squeal.

I thought the first 3 have a clutch squeal, but didn't know what the fourth is.
